# IOS: how to join 2 Dictionaries into 1 dictionary??

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

in my project i applied the following code

```
NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
    NSLog(@"str : %@",dict6);


    diagnosisdict = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"diagnoses"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"DiagnosesHospitals"];

    diagnosedictforname = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"diagnoses"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Diagnoses"];
        NSLog(@" for ref id =%@ ,name of diagnose=%@   data is= %@",refidstr,diagnosedictforname ,diagnosisdict);
```

and the output in console is comes out as in the form

```
str : {
    diagnoses =     (
                {
            Diagnoses =             {
                "diagnosis_name" = "TRANSIENT ISCHEMIA";
            };
            DiagnosesHospitals =             {
                "charge_amt" = "1300.00";
                discharges = "11200.00";
                "hospital_id" = 3341;
                id = 163080;
                "medicare_amt" = "100.00";
                "total_amt" = "1100.00";
            };
        }
    );
    response = 200;
}

ref id =3341 ,name of diagnose={
    "diagnosis_name" = "TRANSIENT ISCHEMIA";
}   data is= {
    "charge_amt" = "1300.00";
    discharges = "11200.00";
    "hospital_id" = 3341;
    id = 163080;
    "medicare_amt" = "100.00";
    "total_amt" = "1100.00";
}
```

now i just want to embed the values of both the Dictionaries into one dictionary 
someone please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a mutable copy of the first dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary * mutDic = [dic1 mutableCopy];
```

and then:

```
[mutDic addEntriesFromDictionary:dic2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
NSLog(@"str : %@",dict6);


NSMutableDictionary *diagnosisdict = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"diagnoses"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"DiagnosesHospitals"];

NSDictionary *diagnosedictforname = [[[dict6 objectForKey:@"diagnoses"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Diagnoses"];

NSArray *keys = [diagnosedictforname allKeys];
for (int i =0; i < keys.count; i++) {
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
    [diagnosisdict setValue:[diagnosedictforname valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
}

NSLog(@"your dic -> %@", diagnosisdict);
```